# Escape character not working

Tags: support, questions, answers, escape-character

The escape character not working with the code I write in the questions or answers (but not in the comment).

I can't write:

```
`\`something\``
```

As inline code, it appears like `\`something``, but it should be:

```
`address 1`
```

If I want to write `\`, it shouldn't be:

```
`\`
```

but

```
`\\`
```

### edit

the way to do so as to use

```
`` `something` ``
```

it will appears like `` `something` ``

**but** it doesn't work like in comments so why this confusion to do the things in comments differently than the questions and answers i still believe that they should allow the escape character in the inline code for answers and questions but it's not essential now , even so if developers make that it will be a good thing for alot of people